# Rank within groups in R with special NA handling

Tags: r

I have a dataframe like this:

```
df <- data.frame(
  A = rep(c("A", "B", "C", "D"), each = 3),
  B = rep(c("V1", "V2", "V3"), 4),
  C = c(1,2,3,5,2,NA,4,6,7,3,7,8)
)

# Output
   A  B  C
1  A V1  1
2  A V2  2
3  A V3  3
4  B V1  5
5  B V2  2
6  B V3 NA
7  C V1  4
8  C V2  6
9  C V3  7
10 D V1  3
11 D V2  7
12 D V3  8
```

My goal is to reveice the ranks grouped by column `B` on the values in column `C`. If there is an `NA` value, this should not be part of the ranking at all. The `RANK` column should be filled with `NA`, `NULL` or something like this then. Ties should end in averages.

The result should look like:

```
   A  B  C RANK
1  A V1  1 4
2  A V2  2 3.5
3  A V3  3 3
4  B V1  5 1
5  B V2  2 3.5
6  B V3 NA NA
7  C V1  4 2
8  C V2  6 2
9  C V3  7 2
10 D V1  3 3
11 D V2  7 1
12 D V3  8 1
```

Comment: What did you try so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can group by 'B', `rank` on 'C', specify the `i` with a logical condition to select only the non-NA elements from 'C' and assign (`:=`) the `rank` values to create the 'RANK' column.  By default, the rows that are not used i.e. NA will be NA in the new column

```
library(data.table)
setDT(df)[!is.na(C),  RANK := rank(-C) , B]
df
#    A  B  C RANK
# 1: A V1  1  4.0
# 2: A V2  2  3.5
# 3: A V3  3  3.0
# 4: B V1  5  1.0
# 5: B V2  2  3.5
# 6: B V3 NA   NA
# 7: C V1  4  2.0
# 8: C V2  6  2.0
# 9: C V3  7  2.0
#10: D V1  3  3.0
#11: D V2  7  1.0
#12: D V3  8  1.0
```

Comment: I didn't think about the `data.table` package, because I am not used to this special notation. My tries with `order()` didn't work. Thanks a lot for this solution!

Answer (score 2):

Using the `ave()` function from baseR for ranking the `C` values within the groups `B`

First approach:(*an improved version of the second approach*) Credit: [Henrik](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45858719/rank-within-groups-in-r-with-special-na-handling/45859013#comment78677120_45859013)

```
df$Rank <- with(df, ave(C, B, FUN=function(x) rank(-x, na.last = "keep", 
                                               ties.method = "average")))
```

Second approach:

```
df$Rank <- with(df, ave(C, B, FUN=function(x) rank(-x, ties.method = "average")))
df$Rank[is.na(df$C)] <- NA
```

Output for both approaches:

```
df

#    A  B  C Rank
# 1  A V1  1  4.0
# 2  A V2  2  3.5
# 3  A V3  3  3.0
# 4  B V1  5  1.0
# 5  B V2  2  3.5
# 6  B V3 NA   NA
# 7  C V1  4  2.0
# 8  C V2  6  2.0
# 9  C V3  7  2.0
# 10 D V1  3  3.0
# 11 D V2  7  1.0
# 12 D V3  8  1.0
```

Finally, the `dplyr` approach with same output

```
df %>% group_by(B)  %>%  mutate(rank = rank(-C, na.last = "keep", 
                                            ties.method = "average"))
```

Comment: ...or just `with(df, ave(C, B, FUN=function(x) rank(-x, na.last = "keep", ties.method = "average")))`

Comment: @Henrik Thanks for the improved version of the solution.